# SharePoint 2010 people search results recent content showing no results

Tags: search, user-profile, my-site, user-profile-service, people-search

What are the dependencies for having the "**By *username***" actually work and show recent content within the people search results? I'm assuming the recent content is not just my site content but ALL CONTENT.

Currently, when I hover over this for any user, I see very quickly the "fetching data" message but nothing is ever shown. Similar the next tab in this dialog "More by *username*" also is disabled/blurred out.

Also, when viewing person.aspx at the mysite host the Content tab only lists sites! I'm assuming recent content (documents) should also be shown here too but I maybe wrong on this!?

We do have mysites and social aspects like tagging disabled currently. Is this responsible?

Cheers

Comment: What does your search application crawl sources look like? Does it have an STS:// protocol? Can you explain how your user profile sync is set up, and if it is crawling with a permissive account?

Comment: Crawl is fine. Search results shown for all scopes in use. Project sites, team sites, intranet, people. The issue is that with the users returned on people results the related content is showing nothing. All docs are crawled fine however as they return fine in normal search results!

Comment: The first is Query + Author:User. The second is Author:User (without your keyword query). Is it possible that you have no docs matching the keyword and authored by the user?

Comment: I have lots of documents authored by myself. Nothing shows for me and similar for all my colleagues and further afield. Doing a normal search of author:"name" returns results so nothing wrong there! I don't use the default All Sites scope, doesn't target that scope or anything does it?